# How to search for a specific feature name in a large csv dataframe?

Tags: python

I want to modify a large dataframe so that the remaining columns are features that contain only 2 unique values (eg, True and False) with the exception of the feature class (that contains more than 2 unique values).

I want to remove irrelevant features to simplify/clean the data set. But I need to keep the feature class which is called 'pattern' as this will be needed for predictions.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('Threat_Prediction_Clean.csv')

print (df.nunique())

if df.nunique() < 3:
  dff = df[df.columns[df.nunique()<3]
elif df[df.columns == 'Pattern']:
  dff.append(df[df.columns == 'Pattern'])
```

**Expected result**:

To have a new dataframe (called 'dff') which contains features of only 2 unique data values AND the `'pattern'` feature

**Actual result**:

```py
  File "<ipython-input-33-ccbaf00f5866>", line 29
    elif df[df.columns == 'Pattern']:
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: you're missing a ] in the dff = line.

Comment: Is this line correct: `dff = df[df.columns[df.nunique()<3]`? Hint: count the opening and closing brackets

Answer (score 0):

A few quick comments:

1. To reference a specific column of a dataframe you use df["col_name"] or df.col_name. So instead of your last elif statement you can just append df["Pattern"].The reason you get your error is because your elif statement never checks for a truth condition.
2. You are missing a closing bracket in your if statement. (See ForceBru's comment above.)
3. I don't understand what you are testing for in the if statement when you write df.nunique > 3. From what you wrote you want to preserve columns which have 2 unique values. What you have tests the entire dataframe. Try something like:

   ```
   for col in df.columns:
       if df[col].nunique() < 3:
          #Append column
   ```